# Is it mandatory to use the STUB schema, installed by DXA Media Manager Module?

Tags: web8, dxa, ecl, dxa-1.5, media-manager

We are already using media manager in our Project. Now it has been decided to use the DXA Media Manager Module. So I have installed that module and found a STUB schema has been also installed along with other items.

**Now, my doubts are:**

1. If I use DXA Media Manager Module then, Is it mandatory to use the stub schema that is installed by script?
2. May I use the old one which is already configured in ECL config file?
   If yes, then may I need to update that schema?

Please Suggest -

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you don't have to use the Media Manager ECL Stub Schema provided as part of the DXA Media Manager Module, as long as you ensure that the Schema title is exactly the same (it's the default title for MM ECL Stub Schemas, assuming that the ID of your ECL Mount Point for Media Manager is `mm`).

As of DXA 1.5, there are a few additional metadata fields defined on the DXA Media Manager Module's ECL Stub Schema to support "custom players". These fields are optional; if you don't have those on your ECL Stub Schema, you will always get the "standard players". See http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-ACDAB198-5506-4EB9-980A-EB37117DAD12